# React Native TabBarIOS.Item custom icon not working

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am having problem while implementing TabBarIOS.Item with custom icon (icon.png) in react-native. I can see a white circle but no image.

```
<TabBarIOS
  barTintColor="darkslateblue"
  tintColor="white"
>
  <TabBarIOS.Item
    icon={require('./images/icon.png')}
    onPress={() => { this.setState({ selectedTab: 'blueTab' }); }}
    selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'blueTab'}
    title="Tab1"
  >
    {this._renderContent('#414A8C', 'Blue Tab')}
  </TabBarIOS.Item>
  <TabBarIOS.Item
    badge={this.state.notifCount > 0 ? this.state.notifCount : undefined}
    onPress={() => { this.setState({ selectedTab: 'redTab', notifCount: this.state.notifCount + 1 }); }}
    selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'redTab'}
    systemIcon="history"
  >
    {this._renderContent('#783E33', 'Red Tab', this.state.notifCount)}
  </TabBarIOS.Item>
  <TabBarIOS.Item
    icon={{uri: base64Icon, scale: 3}}
    onPress={() => { this.setState({ selectedTab: 'greenTab', presses: this.state.presses + 1 }); }}
    selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'greenTab'}
    title="More"
  >
    {this._renderContent('#21551C', 'Green Tab', this.state.presses)}
  </TabBarIOS.Item>
</TabBarIOS>
```

**Icon**

[image]

**Output on Simulator**

[image]

Please help me fix this issue.

Comment: can you attach your image also?

Comment: @Cherniv I have added the icon as well. It is a PNG image I got from iconfinder.com

Comment: Such a shame that this question does not get many attention

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?